# Reference request: a name for a commonly used encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

What is the generally accepted name of a 1-byte encoding, where:

1. Code points from 0x0 to 0x7f encode ASCII characters in the same way as in UTF-8.
2. All other code points encode a question mark "?" (Alternatively, the replacement character, U+FFFD)?

For example, a UTF-8 encoded file, containing a single character: the capital Shcha (Щ), when assumed to be encoded in this 1-byte encoding, would have content "??".

I've seen this encoding (mis-)used in the wild, for example downloading archives of activity/messages/posts of a certain social media site, a name of which temporarily escaped my mind, results in files containing "?" instead of Cyrillic characters.

How is such "encoding" called?

Comment: Sounds like ASCII encoding with error replacement :).  You might also be referring to "ANSI" as Windows uses it, where code points are translated into a Windows-localized code page such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and uses ? for replacement.

Comment: Yes, "ASCII encoding with error replacement" sounds good, but not very punchy. Imagine there was a standardized name such as "daft-8". Then in python you could do `some_bytes.decode('daft-8')`. And in Java you could do `javac -encoding "daft-8" MyLittleJavaProgram.java`. It would be so good to have a generally accepted name for this encoding.

Comment: In python for example I have to do now `some_bytes.decode('ascii', 'replace')`, which is all-right, but much typing.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it in Python.  The name of the encoding is `ascii`.  There are options on how to handle errors.  Why do you think there is a name for "encoding-plus-error-handling"?

Comment: Because it would lead to language-and-platform-interoperable, concise way of saying "I've got this from a rusty wire and I have no idea what the original encoding was, nor do I care, so I'm going to assume ASCII and put question marks if it doesn't make sense".

For example `javac -encoding "daft-8" MyLittleJavaProgram.java` would work too.

Comment: It's ASCII. "Mojibake" is a related effect but is not an encoding.